# How can I copy the content of <p:tooltip> in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, tooltip

How can I copy the content of p:tooltip when tooltip is appearing.I am having only text data inside the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PrimeFaces 6.1 and aren't opposed to adding PrimeFaces Extensions to your project, then take a look at the Tooltip component there. It has a 'fixed' attribute, that when set to true the tooltip will not hide when moused over.

[PrimeFaces Extensions Showcase - Tooltip](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/tooltip.jsf)

Comment: No I want to do it in primefaces 6.1 only.